# Force order before offset and max in query

Tags: grails, criteria

I have a query in Grails which is built using `createCriteria()`. How can I force to execute sorting on the result and then apply the offset an max constraints.

Code:

```
def history = Termin.createCriteria().list([max:10, offset:offset]) {
    and{
//some query constraints
}
   order('id', 'desc')
}
```

This would probably do the same:

```
def history = Termin.createCriteria().list([max:10, offset:offset,order:'desc',sort:'id']) {
            and{
        //some query constraints
        }
}
```

The database is postgreSQL 7.5 and the built query looks like this:

```
select
   something
from
   somewhere 
left outer join
    something
       on something
left outer join
   something
        on something 
left outer join
    something
        on something
where
    (
        something
    ) 
order by
    this_.th_id desc limit ? offset ?
```

Answer (score 0):

The sort is already handled correctly by Hibernate when using offset and max in query's.

If you enable output you will see the produced query. In Oracle, for example, they do a trick, since it not contains this function for query's.

Example of generated query:

```
select * from 
( select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from 
  ( <your_query_goes_here, with order by> ) a 
  where ROWNUM <= :MAX_ROW_TO_FETCH )
where rnum  >= :MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH;
```

Comment: Then you need to provide more info. Witch database are you using? What's the produced query?

Comment: I see similar results to what Sergio posted in Oracle.

Comment: @Jacob The [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/queries-limit.html) says that it should work with the order by. Are you sure that you don't have duplicate data in the database? The same query without limit and offset works correctly?